# segmentation fault language c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) from this algorithm. Why?

Does it work when using small value of N and K? For example, N=100 and K=10?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 400       
#define K 30        

int main()
{
int  i,j,k;
int A[K+1][N][N];
for (i=0;i<K+1;i++)
{
  for (j=0;j<N;j++)
  {
      for (k=0;k<N;k++)
      {

           A[i][j][k]=0; 
      }

  }
}
printf("A[%i][%i][%i] \n", i, j,k);
printf("OK");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("A[%i][%i][%i] \n", i, j,k);` should be with `%d` (this do not cause the error, just a hint).

Comment: Um, `%i` and `%d` are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

You are likely exceeding the stack size.

If you are using large values for `K` and `N`, consider putting `A` on the heap.

```
int *A = malloc((K+1) * N * N * sizeof(int));
```

To index into it:

```
A[(i*(K+1) + j)*N + k]=0;
```

(you make want to make a function or macro for that)

And once you are done with `A`,

```
free(A);
```

Comment: @CharlieBurns, yes, though (surprisingly) you did get two upvotes on your answer ;)

Comment: why would it not be : `int *A = malloc(sizeof(int) * (K + 1) * N * N);` ?

Comment: Btw, [do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: You've probably got somewhere in the region of 16MB max to play with on the stack depending on the platform you run this on.  This answer looks highly plausible.

Comment: @pzaenger, because `malloc` returns `void *`. (It's been awhile since I've used C...the cast is not implicit, right?)

Comment: [regarding casting malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I'm confused, can you really alloc a 3d array that way? It won't compile as is.

Comment: @CharlieBurns, see my additional info in the answer.

Comment: Ok, so it's a 1d array. Should the malloc be 'int *A = malloc((K+1) * N * N * sizeof(int));? As it stands, your malloc line won't compile. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create an array with size of 19.2 MB (31*400*400 *4) where 4B is the size of type int. It is not possible to statically allocate more than 8.37MB, use malloc instead.

Comment: Did you mean *not* possible? And stack size varies (widely).

Comment: In Windows the stack defaults to 1MB.

Comment: @PaulDraper: I expect he was thinking of `static int A[K+1][N][N];` either at file or function scope. Because they aren't on the stack, the don't blow the stack away, unlike the on-stack (for normal machines) allocation of automatic local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to just move the array off of the stack and into the data segment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 400       
#define K 30        
int A[K+1][N][N];  // ADD THIS LINE

int main()
{
int  i,j,k;
// REMOVE THIS LINE int A[K+1][N][N];
for (i=0;i<K+1;i++)
{
  for (j=0;j<N;j++)
  {
      for (k=0;k<N;k++)
      {

           A[i][j][k]=0; 
      }

  }
}
printf("A[%i][%i][%i] \n", i, j,k);
printf("OK");
return 0;
}
```